# Недостаток bot.polling()?

Tags: python-3.x, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

Делал большой проект на Python3, Телеграмм бот с множеством функций, из-за скудности багажа знаний и (как я понял это необходимо) кошелька на сервера использовал bot.polling() (Использую pyTelegramBotAPI) и буквально через пол часа бот падает. написал обычного бота для теста отклика через время, думая что перегрузил проект, но нет, в самом деле падает, код:

```
import telebot
import extras


bot = telebot.TeleBot(extras.token)


@bot.message_handler(content_types="text")
def handler_text(message):
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Все ещё в деле')

bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Ошибка в консоли:

```
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\MainWindowsPC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\sit
e-packages\telebot\util.py", line 58, in run
    task(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:/Python/test.py", line 10, in handler_text
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Все ещё в деле')
  File "C:\Users\MainWindowsPC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\sit
e-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 439, in send_message
    reply_markup, parse_mode, disable_notification))
  File "C:\Users\MainWindowsPC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\sit
e-packages\telebot\apihelper.py", line 135, in send_message
    return _make_request(token, method_url, params=payload, method='post')
  File "C:\Users\MainWindowsPC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\sit
e-packages\telebot\apihelper.py", line 54, in _make_request
    timeout=(connect_timeout, read_timeout), proxies=proxy)
  File "C:\Users\MainWindowsPC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\sit
e-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 508, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\MainWindowsPC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\sit
e-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 618, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\MainWindowsPC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\sit
e-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 490, in send
    raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected(
'Remote end closed connection without response',))
```

Что то подобное
Что делать? На систему вебхуков переходить не хочу, не умею, может есть починка полинга?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас проблема с Роскомнадзором. Используйте proxy для подключения чат-бот к серверу Телеграм, если он запущен локально в РФ.

```
from telebot import apihelper
apihelper.proxy = {
    'https': 'socks5h://127.127.127.127:12345'
}
```

Comment: А когда роскомнадзор начал блокировать телеграм?

Comment: @0xdb, Apr 16, 2018

Comment: Странно,ТС это полугодом раньше заметил. Может на нём тренировались.

Answer (score 3):

Сами разработчики telebot'а [предлагают](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/issues/251#issuecomment-278531560) не мудрить и тупо запхнуть polling в вечный цикл и ловить ошибку подключения:

```
while True:
    try:
        bot.polling(none_stop=True)

    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(e)  # или просто print(e) если у вас логгера нет,
        # или import traceback; traceback.print_exc() для печати полной инфы
        time.sleep(15)
```

UPD: с многопоточностью (которая по умолчанию) обнаружились проблемы (при перезапуске polling падало в `can't start thread`), можно их обойти, переключившись на однопоточную версию (в простых случаях подойдёт):

```
bot = telebot.TeleBot(extras.token, threaded=False)
```

Comment: не помогает отлов ошибок, всё рано падает

Comment: @Pudberg как именно падает?

Comment: если запускать на прямую просто выключается, через консоль выдаёт ошибки

Comment: @Pudberg значит вы неправильно переписали код себе, этот код гарантированно рабочий, хотя бы потому что его предложил сам разработчик telebot :)

Comment: ну, я его скопировал :с

Comment: Значит дайте скриншот кода и консоли что ли

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64813/discussion-between-pudberg-and-andreymal).

Answer (score 2):

Есть еще один вариант:

вместо `bot.polling(none_stop=True)` написать `bot.infinity_polling(True)`.

Comment: `bot.infinity_polling()`, `True` в этом случае лишнее (оно прилетает в `timeout=`, если его оставить).